Day of the week picker
I am trying to create a SwiftUI component that let's the user pick the day of the week. Ignoring the UI, the main issue I am facing is, I am trying to avoid using a custom enum such as:
enum Day { case .m, .tu, ... }

and use Swift's Calendar API or any other native one instead. But I am not sure how I can create a binding with multiple dates.
Imagine the following:
I have a UI component that has 7 circles for each day of the week. The circles that the user taps on will be highlighted and added to the list of selected days. I want these days to not be a custom enum, but a native Swift type. I cannot find any type that works for my use case. Any ideas?
/// A horizontal container that picks days
struct DaysPicker: View {
    // a state property needs to be here to add the days to, of type [calendar], [date] or something similar
    
    var listHasDay: Bool {
        true // logic to check if list has the day
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 12) {
            ForEach(1..<8) { day in
                Circle()
                    .fill(
                        listHasDay ? .red : .blue
                    )
                    .frame(
                        width: 10,
                        height: 10
                    )
                    .overlay {
                        Text("\(day)")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture { // add day to list }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the current component. Also please note that the days are repeating, this is for an alarm clock.

There is no special built-in type to represent days of the week. Calendar just uses Ints for everything. Would you like to use an Int as well?

EventKit has EKWeekday, but I wouldn't use it if I'm not also using other EventKit things.

You can use DateComponents but it isn’t quite efficient

As Sweeper has already described, there is no native Swift type for weekdays. In my opinion, the best solution would probably be a separate enum type.
Just as a note: you should also be careful with regard to localization. For example, in some regions the first day of the week is Sunday, while in other regions the first day of the week is Monday.

Thank you all for the feedback, yes I cannot find any native swift day type. I will just go with the enum at this point.

@Amin Don't use the enum, you were on the right track to think that there is a better way to go about it. Check the answer I just posted.

It is very debatable whether the choice of the data type String from Amin's solution, formed from an abbreviated localized weekday designation, is better than using your own type. Such a solution has various weaknesses.
What is missing from the original question, however, is what is to be done with the weekday selection at the end.
For example, whether it will become part of date calculations etc.

@ITGuy Do you mean the data type String from the answer I posted? The state and its data type served as an example since like you mentioned, we don't know much else about the rest of the model.

You say you want something else than an enum for your weekday collection then you say something about multiple bindings and finally about repeating days and I see no trace of the last two in your code. So what exactly are you asking about, is it one, two or three questions or is it even one of those “write all the code for me” kind of questions?

The days of the week are the 7 days following any date, like today. So if you build a list with the next 7 dates from today, you get all the day names in a week, in the order determined by whatever day today is.
To have the list in a specific order, with Monday or Sunday being the first, just find the next Monday or Sunday from today and get the next 7 dates following that date.
You can use the date formatter to format the day names however you like.
For "picking" days, you need a state that holds the day name and an associated bool value:
@State private var daySelections: [(day: String, isSelected: Bool)] = []

You should also have a view representing a specific day and its status, which would accept the day and a binding to the bool value as parameters. This will allow you to style the view representing the day as needed and toggle the selection from that child view.
Here's the working code:
import SwiftUI

// A horizontal container that picks days
struct DaysPicker: View {
    
    //A state to hold the days and their selection status
    @State private var daySelections: [(day: String, isSelected: Bool)] = []
    
    // Computed property to get selected days
    private var selectedDays: [String] {
        daySelections.filter { $0.isSelected }.map { $0.day }
    }
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(daySelections.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    let day = daySelections[index].day
                    
                    DaysCircle(day: day, isSelected: $daySelections[index].isSelected) //pass a binding to the day's isSelected value
                }
            }
            .padding()
            
            VStack {
                Text("Selected days: \(selectedDays.count)")
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    .padding()
                
                ForEach(selectedDays, id: \.self) { day in
                    Text(day)
                        .textCase(.uppercase)
                        .foregroundStyle(.green)
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            daySelections = getDayNames()
        }
    }
    
    //Function to build list of day names with associated bool value for selection
    private func getDayNames() -> [(day: String, isSelected: Bool)] {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E" // "E" gives a short version like "Mon", "Tue"
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let today = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
        
        let weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: today)
        let daysUntilMonday = (9 - weekday) % 7
        let startOfWeek = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysUntilMonday, to: today)!
        
        var daysOfWeek: [(String, Bool)] = []
        for i in 0..<7 {
            if let day = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: i, to: startOfWeek) {
                let dayName = dateFormatter.string(from: day)
                daysOfWeek.append((dayName, false)) // Initialize each day with isSelected as false
            }
        }
        return daysOfWeek
    }
}

struct DaysCircle: View {
    
    //Parameters
    var day: String
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            withAnimation {
                isSelected.toggle()
            }
        } label: {
            Text("\(day)")
                .textCase(.uppercase)
                .font(.caption)
                .fixedSize()
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(isSelected ? .green : .cyan, in: Circle())
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    DaysPicker()
}



This does not consider the repeating days, this just selects the days in the current next seven days, and does not have a repeating behavior which is what I need for an alarm. But thank you for providing a detailed code and response.

What do you mean by repeating days? I thought you needed a way to get the names of days?

So my goal is to use a native Swift type to create a binding to my alarm. Th user selects those days, and the alarm will go off on the selected days in a repeating fashion. I was looking for a native type to achieve that but it seems like that is not possible.
